# Wrong Blog Post Date Showing in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I am getting wrong blog post date on frontend in magento.

This is my code from phtml file of post.

```
$formatType = Mage::getStoreConfig(NeoTheme_Blog_Helper_Data::XPATH_CONFIG_DATETIME_FORMAT_TYPE);
 $format = ($formatType != 'custom')?
    Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat($formatType): 
    Mage::getStoreConfig(NeoTheme_Blog_Helper_Data::XPATH_CONFIG_DATETIME_CUSTOM_FORMAT);
```

and in below html it display date like -

```
<span class="post-time">
                <?php //echo $this->__('Posted On: '); ?> 
                <?php $date = ($this->getPost()->getPostDate() != NULL)? $this->getPost()->getPostDate() : $this->getPost()->getCreatedAt(); ?>
                <?php  echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($date)->toString($format); ?>
                <?php // $timestamp = (int) Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($date)->getTimestamp() ;?>
                <?php // echo date('d D', $timestamp)?><?php // echo date('M', $timestamp)?>
            </span>
```

This is my Database structure

```
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field              | Type                 | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| entity_id          | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| created_at         | timestamp            | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| updated_at         | timestamp            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| status             | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 1                   |                             |
| title              | text                 | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| author             | text                 | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| post_date          | timestamp            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| summary            | text                 | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| content_html       | text                 | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| meta_description   | text                 | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| meta_title         | text                 | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| meta_keywords      | text                 | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| store_ids          | text                 | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| category_ids       | text                 | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| tag_ids            | text                 | NO   |     | NULL                |                             |
| cms_identifier     | varchar(255)         | YES  | UNI | NULL                |                             |
| customer_group_ids | text                 | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| publish_date       | timestamp            | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| use_summary        | smallint(6)          | YES  |     | 1                   |                             |
| root_template      | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| layout_update_xml  | text                 | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

can anyone please help me to find whats wrong with this code. 
In Database it shows correct date.

Comment: did you check you local setting for time for locale option in `system > configuration > general local option` it is correct

Comment: Yes it is correct as per my understanding EST Timezone (America New York)

Comment: in database  saving the `EST Timezone (America New York)`?

Comment: let me check.. can you please explain me this line `<?php $date = ($this->getPost()->getPostDate() != NULL)? $this->getPost()->getPostDate() : $this->getPost()->getCreatedAt(); ?>`

Comment: @QaisarSatti I have updated my question added DB structure. It is not adding any Timezone in table

Comment: i think it is checking the value from database the if the `post_date` is empty then  use `created_at`.

Comment: But then it should show created date. but it is showing any random date.

Comment: if in your database there is GMT time and date then your code is good because megento uses the GMT for saving. `<?php  echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($date)->toString($format); ?>` function will use to show to your local_timezone

Comment: because of this every time you update `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ` this will update the value in database. i think this is poor from coder

Comment: can you please suggest some correction here..  I am newbie in magento

Comment: first remove `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ` this so the date will not update.

Comment: But What If I want to Update blog and it should reflect new date whenever I update blog. Also What should I mention in DB table column `updated_at` I think `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` should be in updated_at

Comment: yes it is correct you have to add there other thing you are good to go after that

Comment: i prefer next time use `http://magento.stackexchange.com/` for magento related question

Answer (score 0):

there are two thing you have to

first remove on update `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` this so the date will not update

use this to set value for `created_At Varien_Date::now()` if you want to do magento way.

```
<?php  $date=Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($date);
       echo date('L d, M Y',strtotime($date)) ?>
```

Comment: How to convert this date `<?php  echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($date); ?>` `Dec 22, 2015 12:48:42 AM` to like this ' Thursday 14, Jul 2016 '

Comment: it is showing nothing. actually page shows nothing when i add you code. I have write this code `<?php  echo Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($date, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_FULL, false); ?>` But it shows output like this `Tuesday, December 22, 2015` how to change it to `Tuesday 22, December 2015`

Comment: @RahulDambare error was in my code updated kindly check